# Why don't Hindus enter temples after certain occasions?

Tags: belief, rituals, culture, customs

We know that if our nearest relatives have passed away, we can't enter temple for 16 days and also if there were any children born, family members and close relative's don't visit temples for 11 days.

I have three questions:

1. What is the reason(s) behind this belief?
2. What are the other occasions like this, except death and childbirth?
3. Is the number of days(banned days in temples) equal for all casts?

Answer (score 6):

These are known as *asucha* related to birth (*sutika*) and death (*mrutika*). There are many rules and regulations regarding these. I briefly give answers to only what you have asked:

1. The reason behind this belief is that, birth and death create impurity for blood related kinsmen. Temples being residing place of gods, who like purity, entering temples are prohibited in such occasions.
2. As far as I know, death and birth are only such occasions where this impurity (*asaucha*) happens.
3. No, the number of days a person will remain impure varies according to the caste. As per the scriptures:

   > A Brahmana shall be pure after ten days, a Kshatriya after twelve, a Vaisya after fifteen, and a Sudra is purified after a month. [Manu - 5.83 / Agni Pu. 157.2]

   There are many more rules for calculating the days of impurity, but the above one is the standard.

Comment: What about first menstruation of a girl in the family? Does this affect? If yes, pls update your answer.... Your answer seems to me incomplete.

Comment: @KiranRS yes, menstruation does make the girl impure to enter into the temple. But it affects only the girl and doesn't affect other relatives.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the vedic science . It is observable that whenever a new seed germinates all the micro organisms and creatures come towards it, hence it is a point of infection as millions of unseen (adrishya sookshma jeevis called krimis) [Charakam krimiprakaranam] come towards it. The same is true for a birth, when protected and nourished by the mother's unparallel protection of placenta when child steps into the world , the mother's body is attacked by millions of bacterias and viruses like HPV, HBV HCV etc. The food according to Indian culture for Mothers where such that it eliminated these viruses eg in kerala ada of peringalam (hill glory bower) a antiviral remedy. Also, she is protected from outside people, who carry millions of micro organisms themselves, which on close contacts could contructively or destructively harm her...

Temples are not places of God, may be those illeterate in our culture may have started believing it, because they are converts in mind looking at semitic religions and their parallels and superimposing them on Indian culture and thus converting themselves unconsiously. Temples were indeed places were people from communities gathered, hence to not spread this infection the relatives etc where prevented from going there and creating contructively or destructively the interactions of these *sooskhma jeevis*, such was the knowledge and care our ancestors had for a happy and harmonious life for all ...

The same applies to death , when a consciousness leaves a body it becomes the fertile ground for millions of bacterias and viruses, the close relatives who never thought this day of departure will come or that death is indeed possible are reminded of death, this opens many avenues of psycho-physical changes in them due to their emotional attachments, ancestors foresaw them and thus inorder protect them and the society, they imposed the restrictions, till they come out of it. The homage payers are also strictly dictated to enter their home only after bath that is after suddhi with water. Water has this property that its crystals changes with the thoughts of the person's mind...(refer page 2 of WIngs of fire by APJ to see his father employing this property to cure people, Quran stresses on this point and the amazing thing is this fact was known to all ancient humans, that is why water was used in all purposes and kriyas and ceremonies with utmost priority

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Scientific speculation is not allowed on this site. Please don't answer from scientific point of view.